# Brownian Motion calculation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am reading the following statement and cannot justify the upper limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

$$
E\left[\exp\left(2\int_{0}^{T}B_{s}^{2}\,{\rm d}s\right)\right] < \infty
\quad\mbox{if and only if}\quad
T < {\pi \over {4}}
$$

Comment: They probably explain somewhere that this is $E(\mathrm e^{2T^2Z})$ where $$Z=\int_0^1B_s^2\mathrm ds$$ is such that $$P(Z\gt z)=\mathrm e^{-\pi^2z/4+o(z)}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no mention of this. I am reading some old notes. Where can I find a proof of this result? Thanks.

Comment: Erdös/Kac obtained the distribution of the random variable $Z$ ([link to paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183507847))... but, unfortunately, the formula is rather messy.

Comment: @Did Do you know a proof of this theorem?

Comment: @saz No, I don't even know if it is true...

Comment: @Did Oh, okay. Good to know...

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1178492/