# What is $\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\int_0^t B_s^2ds\right)\right]$?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, expected-value

Let $(B_t)$ a Brownian motion. I know that $$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\mu_X(dx),$$

So, logically if $$f(B_s)=\exp\left(\int_0^t B_s^2ds\right)$$
then $$\mathbb E[f(B_s)]=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{\int_0^tx^2dt}\mu_{B_s}(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{x^2t}\mu_{B_s}(dx).$$

But this doesn't really look correct. Indeed, if $f(x)=e^{\int_0^t x^2ds}$, then $$f(B_s)=e^{B_s^2\int_0^tds}=e^{B_s^2t}$$
and $$f(B_s)=e^{\int_0^t B_s^2ds}\neq e^{B_s^2t},$$
so something goes wrong here. Any idea ?

---

Note that I just want to prove that $$\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\int_0^t B_s^2ds\right)\right]<\infty .$$

Comment: $f(B_s) =\exp(\left( \int_0^t B_s^2 \, ds \right)$ doesn't make sense. If you fix some $s \geq 0$ (on the left-hand side) you cannot use it as a variable of integration on the right-hand side. Note that $\exp \left( \int_0^t B_s^2 \, ds\right)$ depends on the whole path $(B_s)_{s \leq t}$ and not only one single value; therefore the very first formula in the body of your question is not applicable.

Comment: Re your original question: The expectation is only finite for small $t$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/848532/36150) and also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1178492/36150)